# jQuery Cannot call method 'get' of null

Tags: jquery

I'm getting a **Cannot call method 'get' of null**

It works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RJMhT/1/

```
<script>
var divs = $("div.Image").get().sort(function(){
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
}).slice(0,1) 
    $(divs).appendTo(divs[0].parentNode).show();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your script to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var divs = $("div.Image").get().sort(function() {
               return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/-              combo
               }).slice(0,1)

    $(divs).appendTo(divs[0].parentNode).show();
});
</script>
```

This will allow your script to wait until the DOM has finished loading before it executes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes browsers pretend to be very nicely about loading jQ, without being encapsulated in block. Try with `$(document).ready(function() {` block first. If that does not solve your problem, there is also chance of jQ to be conflicted w/ something else, so give a try by changing all $() calls, with jQuery().

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes jquery pretend to be very nicely about loading jQ, without being encapsulated in block. Try with `jQuery.(document).ready(function() {` block first. and use the correct jquery  like [enter link description here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js)